# Pycharm - Install packages

Tags: python, package, pycharm

So I created my project with a virtual environment and installed pip + distribute. Everything is fine so far, But when I click on the install button to install new packages it displays a beautiful : "Nothing to show".

Here is an image of it :

[image]

I have the [default repository](http://pypi.python.org/pypi)

So what did I do wrong? Is this not the right way to install python modules like PIL or third party django apps like django south ?

Edit : I forgot to mention , it's the trial version... Can this be because of it ?

Comment: Works fine for me. Anything else about your setup that is unusual? Can you install stuff using `pip` from the command line?

Comment: How do you use the command line  ? :s
I only see python and django console

Comment: I haven't used Windows in a while, but run -> cmd.exe, then type `pip install some-package` and see if it works (you may need to add `X:\path\to\python\Scripts` to your system path, or give the full path to the command).

Comment: aaah you mean the windows command line ? aah thought there was an integrated shell in pycharm. I'm going to check

Comment: Works as expeted on windows command line ( but i already knew that  because I used to do this way) But i decided to try Pycharm because of all the features it has... but if i cant even install a simple package ....

Comment: @philippe87 I think this is the less useful feature of PyCharm. If you try it for a bit more time you'll see that, even without this, PyCharm is a really good IDE. By the way, on linux it works perfectly out of the box.

Comment: @Bakuriu I totally agree with you but i consider that as a Basic feature and I would like to make it work :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by recent server-side changes in PyPI, and will be addressed in the PyCharm 2.7.1 update. Please see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-8962 to track the status of the issue.

Comment: Any updates? I still see the issue. I tried to install community edition of Pycharm community edition 4.0.6 on windows 8 machine

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy (e.g. in a corporate environment), then you may need to configure your proxy settings for PyCharm to show the packages.

These are in Pycharm under:

> File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy

Enter your proxy settings there, e.g. a host name and port number.

If you don't know your proxy settings then this question may be useful: [How to see the proxy settings on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368515/how-to-see-the-proxy-settings-on-windows/30751938#30751938)

Answer (score 0):

I faced such problem man y times and every time I found that the problem corresponds to my internet connection. check your internet connection with tools like wget or curl in linux and browsers in windows.