# How to see the proxy settings on windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, proxy, command-prompt

Our work laptops are configured to use proxy to access external sites and I don't have access to see the proxy information. All our applications like IDEs are configured to use system proxy. Is there a way I can check the proxy settings; For example, on chrome or command prompt or any other ways?

Comment: Does anyone know what needs to be done so that webkit can read  the proxy settings variable ( `PS C:\> $env:HTTPS_PROXY`) under windows?

Answer (score 75):

It's possible to view proxy settings in Google Chrome:

> chrome://net-internals/#proxy

Enter this in the address bar of Chrome.

Comment: In my case this shows the proxy SCRIPT address but not the current proxy server address itself.

Comment: @DaveInCaz Just view the proxy address in the pac file.

Comment: @roadrunner some pac scripts I have seen are complex with conditional logic so they are non trivial to understand...

Comment: @DaveInCaz Understandable. Ussually they ussually show up as `PROXY <address>` in the pac file, atleast the ones Ive seen. Another alternative is to use a pac file parser such as [pacparser](https://github.com/manugarg/pacparser).

Comment: As of Chrome 71, it appears that this has been stripped down such that it no longer shows proxy settings.

Comment: @ZachBloomquist see my improved answer here of how to get around this: https://superuser.com/questions/33588/how-to-view-internet-explorer-auto-detected-proxy-settings#1211548

Answer (score 19):

You can use a tool called: [NETSH](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/242468)

To view your system proxy information via command line:

```
netsh.exe winhttp show proxy
```

Another way to view it is to open IE, then click on the "gear" icon, then Internet options -> Connections tab -> click on LAN settings

Comment: This does not work. I know for a fact I have a proxy enforced by my organization. NETSH shows nothing.

Answer (score 16):

Other 4 methods:

1. **From Internet Options** (but without opening Internet Explorer)

Start > Control Panel > Network and Internet > Internet Options > Connections tab > LAN Settings
2. **From Registry Editor**

- Press <kbd>Start</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- Type `regedit`
- Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > Internet Settings
- There are some entries related to proxy - probably **ProxyServer** or **AutoConfigURL** is what you need to open (double-click) if you want to take its value (data)

3. **Using PowerShell**

   ```
    Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' | findstr ProxyServer
   ```

Output:

```
    ProxyServer               : proxyname:port
```

4. **Mozilla Firefox**

Type the following in your browser:

```
    about:preferences#advanced
```

Go to Network > (in the Connection section) Settings...

Comment: In case of **proxy auto-config** you can get the PAC file URL in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AutoConfigURL`

Answer (score 12):

> You can figure out which proxy server you're using by accessing some
> websites with a browser and then running the DOS command:
>
> `netstat`
>
> You'll see some connections in the *Foreign Address* column on port 80
> or 8080 (common proxy server ports).

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/8161865/3195477)

Ideally you will be able to identify the proxy server by its naming convention.

Comment: This is by far the most direct way, on a locked down corporate PC.

Comment: So simple I bet it woudln't work. And here I am using the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

An update to @rleelr:
It's possible to view proxy settings in Google Chrome:

> chrome://net-internals/#http2

Then select

> View live HTTP/2 sessions

Then select one of the live sessions (you need to have some tabs open). There you find:

```
[...]
t=504112 [st= 0] +HTTP2_SESSION  [dt=?]
                  --> host = "play.google.com:443"
                  --> proxy = "PROXY www.xxx.yyy.zzz:8080"
[...]
                              ============================
```

Comment: When I tried that chrome:// URL it immediately redirects me to chrome://net-internals/#events and does not show any "view live..." link. Chrome v75

Comment: Google Chrome 76 reports: "The net-internals events viewer and related functionality has been removed. Please use chrome://net-export to save netlogs and the external catapult netlog_viewer to view them."

Comment: This helped. Use "chrome://net-export" instead.