# pip install requests error

Tags: python, installation, pip, python-requests

Trying to install requests, getting the following error message. I also tried to manually download them and run the same code based off local files, but I was running into the same issue. I don't think it is on the requests side, as I am getting the same error message if I try to download anything through pip.

```
C:\Users\212615669>pip install requests
Collecting requests
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x031251D0>: Failed to establish a new c
onnection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/requests/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03125190>: Failed to establish a new c
onnection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/requests/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03125090>: Failed to establish a new c
onnection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/requests/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03121FD0>: Failed to establish a new c
onnection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/requests/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03121EB0>: Failed to establish a new c
onnection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/requests/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests (from version
s: )
No matching distribution found for requests
```

Comment: This error is regarding internet connectivity not requests library installation

Comment: They are using a proxy

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -H pip install requests --proxy="my_proxy_name:port"
```

Try this

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but what exactly would be proxy be? Is there a way to do it with like localhost?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368515/how-to-see-the-proxy-settings-on-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Easy method is to give the proxy information.

```
 pip install --proxy=user:pass@server:port requests
```

2nd method is using exporting proxy setting

```
set http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyAddress:port
set https_proxy=https://username:password@proxyAddress:port
pip install requests
```

Comment: Wait how do I get my proxy information? Is that where I put like localhost or something?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368515/how-to-see-the-proxy-settings-on-windows

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble finding my proxy information (similar to other users on that thread I don't directly control my network). Do you know of any other way to download it? I have the zip with the files downloaded which I believe contains everything

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me with a development Vagrant virtual machine that I started up (i.e. via `vagrant up` while the internet was down. I guess, it after it came back on, the network settings were never updated.

All I had to do was halt the VM and restart it. The problem went away.

Maybe this helps someone.