# Obtain Chrome proxy settings when set by administrator

Tags: google-chrome, intellij-idea, proxy

I can access internet with Chrome, but cannot in IntelliJ, I guess a proxy is responsible.

I can't see the proxy settings in Chrome, as it disabled (configured by administrator of your organization).

Running `netsh winhttp show proxy` on Windows shows `DirectAccess (no proxy server)`. Accessing `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`is blocked on my computer.

How can I find out which Proxy Chrome is using?

Comment: Check these: https://superuser.com/questions/346372/how-do-i-know-what-proxy-server-im-using and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368515/how-to-see-the-proxy-settings-on-windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see the proxy settings on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368515/how-to-see-the-proxy-settings-on-windows)